# "an internal error occurred shile enumerating backup sets"

Tags: windows-vista, backup, restore

I have a Windows Vista complete pc backup, when i try to restore from backup.
I got this error "an internal error occurred while enumerating backup sets".
Full backup is store on external USB HDD.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same problem with you .. Take a look [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistamigration/thread/cb7c6825-9917-4231-a595-fdc6e072004d)

> It's possible that the folder I copied
>   was corrupted somehow.  So, I just
>   deleted it from my USB hard drive
>   after doing a Drive Check (with only 
>   a  File System Fix, from
>   properties->tools the Drive Check
>   button -- basically a checkdisk from
>   explorer in Vista).  I had also copied
>   this folder to the Folder in Which MS
>   keeps the backup sets.  Anyway, after
>   deleting it, I don't anymore get the
>   error 'An internal error occured while
>   enumerating backup sets'.  Now I'm
>   restoring from my USB external drive
>   with no problem.  Essentially, the
>   reason this problem occurs suddenly is
>   that something gets corrupted on the
>   Drive you restore to from